# Is there an excel formula to show a drop down calendar when ever i click on the dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wsp

[image]

I wanted to know if there was such thing as a drop down calendar for excel whenever i click on the dates. So that it would be a better reference for me when choosing dates.

Comment: no, there is no formula that will do this.

Comment: ^^^^ there is no such formula, you can use this addin [DatePicker](http://samradapps.com/datepicker) and to create a drop down for dates, you need to store those dates in some sheets and use it as a reference in the list range

Comment: You might obtain the desired result with VBA.